# I want inductively prove that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all n.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction

Define a function $f(x)$ such that:

\begin{cases}
\exp(-1/x^2), & \text{if } x>0, \\
0, & \text{if } x\leqslant 0. \\
\end{cases}

I want to inductively prove that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n \geqslant 0$. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo You surely meant $P_n(1/x)e^{-1/x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show by induction that for each integer $n$, there exists a polynomial $P_n$ such that if $x\neq 0$ then 
$$f^{(n)}(x)=P_n\left(\frac 1x\right)\exp\left(-\frac 1{x^2}\right).$$
Put $P_0(X)=1$ and if $P_n$ works, then 
\begin{align}
f^{(n+1)}(x)&=-\frac 1{x^2}P'_n\left(\frac 1x\right)
\exp\left(-\frac 1{x^2}\right)+P_n\left(\frac 1x\right)\frac 2{x^3}\exp\left(-\frac 1{x^2}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac 2{x^3}P_n\left(\frac 1x\right)-\frac 1{x^2}P'_n\left(\frac 1x\right)\right)\exp\left(-\frac 1{x^2}\right).
\end{align}
We define 
$$P_{n+1}(X)=2X^3P_n(X)-X^2P'_n(X),$$
which is well-defined and completes the induction.